# htaccess rewrite match question mark

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need help with rewrite rule and regular expression

This is my input url

```
http://localhost/ws/rest/user/login?login=user_login&password=user_pass
```

I want it to redirect into this

```
http://localhost/index.php?type=rest&ressource=user&action=login&login=user_login&password=user_pass
```

My rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(GET|POST)
RewriteRule ^ws/(.+)/(.+)/([A-Za-z]+)(\\?)(.+)?   index.php?type=$1&ressource=$2&action=$3&$5 [L]
```

I think the problem is around the `?` in the url because when I replace with a `&` it works ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(GET|POST)
RewriteRule ^ws/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([A-Za-z]+) index.php?type=$1&resource=$2&action=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Notice the [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag so that the query string from the original URL is appended to the new URL.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** `QUERY_STRING` isn't matched in `RewriteRule`. Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^login=user_login&password=user_pass$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ws/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ /index.php?type=$1&ressource=$2&action=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Your existing `QUERY_STRING` will be appended to resulting URI due to use of `QSA` flag here.

#### Read more about it here: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)